# Why Taylor Swift says "The story of us" but not "The story of ours"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, questions, pronouns

I have a problem in understanding this type of relation between object and possessive pronouns. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: People in a couple relationship often refer to it as 'us'. The story of our relationship as a couple.

Answer (score 1):

"The story of ours", or more likely "a story of ours", most likely would mean a story that belongs to us, in the sense that we own it; maybe we own the copyright. It doesn't mean that the story is about us.
"The story of 'us'" means a story about us, that is, we are the subject of the story.  Note the extra punctuation that I put around "us". This is to show that it is an unusual use of the word, meaning "us as a couple", as pointed out in the comment.

Now, if it said "our story", that could have either meaning: owned by us, or about us.